# conjoin 2 ponds

Tags: construction

I'm trying to design a temporary water barrier so I can conjoin 2 ponds.  I have a new pond 2-3' distance between each other.  I'd like to move my fish and most of the water from the old pond into the new pond with the barrier on the inside of the new pond, wider than the proposed channel I need to excavate.  The liner for the new pond would be in place with the remaining portion still rolled up and waiting between the old and new.  Once I excavate an approx 4' width by 44" height channel, I'd then roll the rest of the liner into the channel and into the old pond (after removing the old smaller liner).  The idea is to keep the trauma and work to a minimum as the old cycled pond water is very important to the pond's health.  Also, it saves on needing a temporary 'holding' tank/pool for the fish.  I'd end up with a double sized pond half-filled with 'cycled' pond water.  I could then slowly fill it up.

So, I'm thinking of some sort of sluice gate which I can put into the new pond, sealed at the sides and bottom, while supported by the earth barrier between, except for the 4' or so I'm going to excavate.  Once done, I can hopefully lift the gate out slowly, allowing the new pond to flow into the 'newer' old pond.

So, what sort of dimension wood would I need?  What type of seal and protection for the new liner against the wood gate?  What if I wanted to make it 6-8' instead of 4'?

And anything else I haven't thought of!

If you can help, I'd really appreciate it.

new pond gallonage and rough dimensions; 5' deep, roughly oval, 8' width, 16' length.  This new pond will be about 1.5' deeper than the old one.  Gallonage approx 4200.

Michael

[image]

Comment: Not sure this falls in the category of "Home Improvement".

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, as @MichaelKaras said, this isn't on-topic here. Please take our tour to see how better to participate.

Comment: I think the sluice gate is overly complicated. I don't think you'll be able to mitigate leaking and the weight/pressure of the pond water will be formidable. Especially built out of wood on little or no experience. I'd construct the "new" pond and pump as much of the water over from the old one as you think you'll need to get it established and get them to roughly the same level. Then when you're ready, start removing the barrier between the two ponds and fill it the rest of the way when you've joined the liners.

Comment: well, I was hoping that someone dealing with construction issues would be able to help re the force against the wood barrier I'm trying to design.  I posted in an engineering forum as well, but haven't had much luck with assistance.  I figured someone here might know how much force/load I'm dealing with and the ability to design something sturdy enough. I'm not joining two liners, I'm trying to enlarge the pond with a new liner while keeping the old water at bay while I excavate the earth between old and new, then lay in the rest of the liner.  Thanks for the help!